# Should I name final `Atomic…` member fields as constants (in all uppercase) per Java conventions?

Tags: java, constants, naming-conventions, atomic

When defining a variable of a type of one of [the `Atomic…` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), and marking it `final` to avoid replacement, is such a variable considered to be a constant?

The object reference contained in the named variable will not change, because of the `final`. Yet the `Atomic…` object is really just a protective wrapper around a payload, a value that may well be changing.

The point of my question is the Java naming conventions. By convention, constants such as a `final` member field or `final static` should be named in all-uppercase. So I came to wonder about how to name the object reference of a `Atomic…` such as [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Here is a contrived example class.

➥ Should the `final private AtomicInteger` be named `count` or `COUNT`?

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class CountUp
{
    final private AtomicInteger count;  //  `count` or `COUNT` ?

    public CountUp ( )
    {
        this.count = new AtomicInteger();
    }

    public int increment ( )
    {
        return this.count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getCount ( )
    {
        return this.count.get();
    }
}
```

You might think this Question of duplicate of ones such as [*Should a “static final Logger” be declared in UPPER-CASE?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1417190/642706) or [*Should I use upper-case naming to declare java constant variables?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10978338/642706). But no. I believe the nature of `Atomic…` objects puts a spin on the issue.

My first thought is: *Context is everything.* In conversation regarding specifically thread-safety issues, I would refer to the `AtomicInteger` as a constant. But in the context of the business logic, the payload of the `Atomic` is meant to be changing. I would not consider an `Atomic` to be effectively a constant. So I lean to naming with the usual [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Comment: Your use of AtomicInteger in that sample should not be considered a constant. For one thing, you can increment it.

Comment: I have not encountered final instance fields being capitalized regardless of `Atomic`.

Comment: Since we're talking about convention: `final private AtomicInteger` -> `private final AtomicInteger`

Comment: Imo, if the essence of the variable or class can be changed, then it should not be considered a constant.  This would pertain to mutable classes where you don't want the reference to change but the contents may vary throughout time.  It those cases I would not capitalize it.

Comment: @NomadMaker The twist here is that the final variable `count` never changes its actual contents. The pointer to the `AtomicInteger` always has one permanent value, always pointing to the very same `AtomicInteger` object. The object reference is literally constant. But this constancy is shallow, as its payload is mutable.

Comment: I usually only use all-uppercase for *static* final fields, so in this example: definitely no. I think that’s a rather common convention.

Comment: @Axel Good point, the Google code guidelines I quoted below actually say that all upper case should only be used for static immutable fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's code style guidelines says that final fields that reference a mutable object are not considered "constants" and are not capitalized.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

To quote section **5.2.4 Constant names:**

> But what is a constant, exactly?
>
> Constants are static final fields whose contents are deeply immutable and whose methods have no detectable side effects. This includes primitives, Strings, immutable types, and immutable collections of immutable types. If any of the instance's observable state can change, it is not a constant. Merely *intending* to never mutate the object is not enough.

Some examples from that section:

```
// Not constants
static String nonFinal = "non-final";
final String nonStatic = "non-static";
static final Set<String> mutableCollection = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks. The phrase “deeply immutable” solved it for me. The programmer reading an all-uppercase field name should be able to rely on the fact that nothing about its contents will ever be changing.